# Join the three tables

Tags: sql, database

I do not know where is my code error. 
I want join three tables together.

i have three tables

**user_type**

```
id_user_type(pk) | user_type
```

**user_type_page_access**

```
id_user_type(fk) | id_page_access(fk)
```

**page_access**

```
id_page_access(pk) | page | roll
```

i want select `id_user_type`, `roll`, `page`

and this my query is Sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FindRollOfUser
(
@id_user_type int
)
as
select 
u1.id_user_type,
p.page,
p.roll 
from user_type as u1 
where u1.id_user_type=@id_user_type
join user_type_page_access as u2
on u1.id_user_type=u2.id_user_type
join page_access as p
on p.id_page_access=u2.id_page_access
RETURN
```

thank you......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous SQL is good but base on the table name I think add some join type will be better:

```
 select 
 u1.id_user_type,
 p.page,
 p.roll 
 from user_type as u1 
 left join user_type_page_access as u2
 on u1.id_user_type=u2.id_user_type
 left join page_access as p
 on p.id_page_access=u2.id_page_access
 where u1.id_user_type=@id_user_type
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is because you specify the `where` clause before the `join`. Swap the order and you should be fine:

```
select 
u1.id_user_type,
p.page,
p.roll 
from user_type as u1 
join user_type_page_access as u2
on u1.id_user_type=u2.id_user_type
join page_access as p
on p.id_page_access=u2.id_page_access
where u1.id_user_type=@id_user_type
```

For future reference, the order in which clauses should appear when **writing** the query is:

1. `select`
2. `join`
3. `where`
4. `group by`
5. `having`
6. `order by`

The order of evaluation of these clauses by the DBMS is not the above however.